# Ich vermute nicht

Tags: word-order, grammaticality, negation, semantics

I noticed that German speaker often use phrases like

> Ich vermute nicht, dass das [let's call it A] stimmt.

What do they mean? Do they mean that they conjecture that A is false? Or do they mean that they just do not want to claim that A is true (and maybe do not have an opinion in neither direction)?

How to unambiguously express

1. that one conjectures A to be false
2. that one just does not want to conjecture that A is true?

Comment: Ja. (Hier Füllkommentar)

Comment: In everyday communication they mean "I think A is not true", not "I don't think that A is true" (in its formally logical meaning). Everyday language does not follow formal logics. For formal logics, see Janka's answer below. For practical everyday use of language, see my separate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words **nicht** and **kein** precede the item negated. If *nicht* is the last word of a main clause, it negates the predicate verb and thus, the whole clause. In subordinate clauses, the word order is changed and the verbs occupy the end of the clause. *Nicht* simply precedes the verbs then as it does with all other negated items.

> Ich vermute nicht, dass A stimmt.
>
> <s>Ich nicht vermute, dass A stimmt.</s> *(nicht goes to the end in main clauses)*

*I don't assume A is correct.*

> Ich vermute, dass A nicht stimmt.

*I assume A is not correct.*

> Nicht ich vermute, dass A stimmt.

*It's not me who assumes A is correct.*

> Ich vermute, dass nicht A stimmt (sondern B).

*I assume not A is correct (but B).*

Comment: This answer is on the level of semantical logic. It is okay for getting aware of the structure of language. However, for everyday use of language it is misleading. People saying *Ich vermute nicht, dass xyz* in everyday situations do not want to say that they "do not suppose xyz", they want to say that they "suppose xyz not to happen". They do not follow the strict logic you laid out here.

Comment: *Ich vermute nicht, dass sie da ist.* means *I don't know if she's here, but if you ask about what I assume …*

Comment: As I said, you are right in terms of formal logic, but in everyday use of language, things are the other way round. People who say "Ich glaube nicht, das das noch was wird" do usually intend to actually say: "Das wird nichts mehr" ("This will not work"). There is a difference in logical semantics and pragmatics.

Comment: Vielen Dank euch!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I think, these meanings you mention persist in the english translation given by Janka.

Answer (score 1):

Während Jankas Antwort auf Ebene der formalen semantischen Logik richtig ist, stehen die Dinge auf Ebene der alltäglichen (nicht zwangsläufig formal-logisch konsequenten) Sprachverwendung anders.

In Alltagssituationen sagt man im Deutschen oft Dinge wie

> Ich denke nicht, dass es morgen regnen wird

und meint damit aber: "Ich denke, dass es morgen nicht regnen wird." Das *nicht* hat dabei einen Sprung gemacht vom "nicht regnen" zum "nicht denken". Gleichwohl ist die primäre Intention des Sprechers, sich über das Regnen zu äußern, nicht über sein Denken.

Weitere Beispiele:

> Ich glaube nicht, dass das ein gutes Konzert wird.

Bedeutet: "Ich glaube, dass das kein gutes Konzert wird."

> Ich glaube nicht, dass du recht hast.

Bedeutet: "Ich meine, dass du nicht recht hast."

Comment: Vielen Dank! Sehr hilfreich!

Comment: Wenn du überall, wo du *bedeutet* geschrieben hast, *kann bedeuten* geschrieben hättest, wäre deine Antwort richtiger.